# FMDB query find no result in iOS

Tags: ios, sql, fmdb

```
NSString *query = @"select * from 'topic' where 'group' = ? order by lastUpdatedAtFloat desc";
FMResultSet * rs = [db executeQuery:query, groupUuid];
while ([rs next]) {
    NSLog(@"show");
}
```

This is the query that I used, but no result is found while I am sure my database tables have data inside.

I know that FMDB query has quite some questions similar to my case, but I have not seen any reported correct demo or document for the best practice to choose which query method in the following to use for different scenarios.

```
- (FMResultSet *)executeQuery:(NSString *)sql;
- (FMResultSet *)executeQuery:(NSString *)sql withParameterDictionary:(NSDictionary *)arguments;
- (FMResultSet *)executeQuery:(NSString *)sql withArgumentsInArray:(NSArray*)arrayArgs orDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryArgs orVAList:(va_list)args;
```

Can anyone point me a way out?

Comment: does your parameter `groupUuid ` wrap as NSObject? As far as I know, you need to wrap your parameter to NSObject before passing it to the query parameter. In you case, you may need to wrap it as NSNumber like `@(groupUuid)`

Comment: `'Topic' ? 'group' ? `

Comment: @Enix groupUuid here is a NSString.

Comment: @Sami 'topic' is a table name in the database. And 'group' is a field name, but due to it is also a SQL name, so I wrap it up by single quote.

Comment: how about this? wrapping your ? with single quote. `select * from topic where group = '?'`

Comment: `"select * from topic where group = '?' order by lastUpdatedAtFloat desc";`

Comment: @Enix this will generate an syntax error if `group` is not wrapped. And I tested that the single quote for `question mark` is not necessary.

Comment: @Sami First, `group` must be wrapped otherwise a syntax error. I would think about to rename the field names, clash with system names is a disaster.

Comment: how about turning on the debug option `db.traceExecution = YES` and see what sql is being executed when you submit it. If still no help, i recommend you to build the sql with plain String like `select * from topic where group='123asdasda'` and check if any record could be found.

Comment: @Enix good suggestion and I would try it later. Now I have solved the problem by bypassing it, I renamed the `group` field to `group_uuid`, and all of them works well now. I guess those system defined keywords are somehow blocked by FMDB or sqlite, or at least triggers some hidden bugs. And from the FMDB documents, those query methods all should work well. It is most probable of that `group` word caused the problem.

Comment: glad to hear that. :-)